# Why can't I call functions from another file?

Tags: c++

So I have two files, `baseline.h` and `baseline.cpp`. In `baseline.h`, I have created a class that declares multiple functions and variables, with a sample of one here:

```cpp
#pragma once

class entity
{
protected:
    int x;
    int y;

public:
    void spawn(int bx, int by);
}
```

`baseline.cpp` tries to define the function as such:

```cpp
#include "baseline.h"

void entity::spawn(int bx, int by)
{
    x = //functionality
    y = //functionality
}
```

I keep being met with the same errors: `'entity': is not a class or namespace name`, followed by `'x': undeclared identifier` and `'y': undeclared identifier`.

Am I missing something incredibly obvious here?

Comment: Yes, a semicolon :) I'll let you find it

Comment: Do study the duplicate. C++ requires a `;` after the class declaration for good reasons. Compilers are not very good at issuing a good error message in such cases, due to the complexity of the language grammar. Upvoted the question though: this is not at all obvious on a first encounter and your question is well-written.